# Do irreversibilites change the final temperatures of two bodies?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy, reversibility

When two identical bodies are brought into thermal contact, and both are surrounded by an isolation, does the fact that they have a finite temperature difference, which generates entropy, change their final temperatures. Are their final temperatures their arithmetic average

Comment: By the way in general case the specific heat is a function of temperature so in general case final temperature is not the arithmetic average

Comment: You commented the following regarding my original and subsequently deleted answer "I read that irreversible heat transfer is due to entropy generation less useful according to the area under the T-S diagram where a rev. heat transfer corresponds to a larger area than the irrev. one. As justification there was the sentence that heat is a path function and its value depends one the path taken. So I concluded that irreversible heat transfer decreases the actual heat transferred and therefore the temperature does not rise like in a rev. HT. Process"

Comment: I realized that I didn’t fully understand what you read not seeing it in context. Are you able to edit your question to cite the source and proved the context of what your read?

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist I think this is an answer. Why not post it like that?

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski I don't think AlekseyDruggist comment is an answer. I believe the OP is assuming the heat capacity is constant over the specified temperature range and wants to know whether or not entropy generation alters the final temperature, which it does not, and why

Comment: @Claudio Saspinski,  I think this question and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567587/what-is-the-difference-between-entropy-generation-and-entropy-transfer ) are identical, and the answer given by  Chet Miller clarifies things. As to final temperature its calculation is based on the conservation of energy, so taking into account the temperature dependence $c(T)$ instead of $T_1+T_2 = 2T_f$ we shell have $ \phi(T_1)+\phi(T_2)=2 \phi(T_f)$,where $\phi$ is some function arising from the integration .This does not change the essence of the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Aleksey Druggist I think consideration of temperature dependence of $C$ unnecessarily complicates matters. The OP only wants to know if entropy generation changes the final equilibrium temperature. We can just assume $C$ is constant over the limited temperature range $T_1$ to $T_2$.

Comment: @Bob, that is why I used the expression "by the way"